# Derivative of $f(x) = 1+ \cos x + \frac{\cos^2(x)}{2} + \frac{\cos^3(x)}{6} +\dots$

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

My attempt: This series represents the Taylor series expansion of $e^{\cos x}$. Hence 
$$f'(x) = -\sin x \cdot e^{\cos x}.$$ Am I right?

Comment: you are right, m8

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Correct, but in the future, please use MathJax to format your equations.

Comment: This is correct only if we can justify that the sequence of denominators (of which we are only given the first terms $1,1,2,6$) is indeed the sequence of factorials ... otherwise it might just as well be http://oeis.org/A002524

Comment: It's correct. Great thinking!

Answer (score 0):

The function in question is $$f(x)=1+\cos(x)+\frac{\cos^2(x)}{2}+\frac{\cos^3(x)}{6}+...=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos^n(x)}{n!}$$

Recalling $e^x=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and substituting $x\rightarrow\cos x$ yields $f(x)=e^{\cos(x)}$ and thus $f'(x)=-\sin(x)e^{\cos(x)}$. So yes, you are correct.

Alternatively you can differentiate a single term of the given series:

$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\frac{\cos^n(x)}{n!}=n\frac{-\sin(x)\cos^{n-1}(x)}{n!}=-\sin(x)\frac{\cos^{n-1}(x)}{(n-1)!}$ by the chain rule (for $n\ge1$). So
$$f'(x)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos^n(x)}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}-\sin(x)\frac{\cos^{n-1}(x)}{(n-1)!}=-\sin(x)\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos^{n-1}(x)}{(n-1)!}$$
Let $n-1\rightarrow n$ to get $f'(x)=-\sin(x)\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos^n(x)}{n!}$ and then finally recall the Taylor series from the beginning to - again - achieve $f'(x)=-\sin(x)e^{\cos(x)}$.